# BIOS not showing windows boot manager

Tags: boot, ssd, bios, grub

So i accidentally removed my ubuntu partition and was prompt to grub rescue. My laptop was was not opening Boot menu for some reason at first so i just removed my ssd and putted in my pc to fix it long story short i got it fixed in my pc but now when i installed my ssd back in laptop it was still showing grub rescue why? But now i can acess my boot menu and it is just showing my previous boot options windows boot manager and ubuntu which is different from what my pc is showing so what can i do to get the bios to be reset because in my pc the ssd is opening windows just fine.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you saying that you can select the "Boot Ubuntu" option and when you hit enter if just sits there? It could be that the Ubuntu boot partition is in a "dirty" state then.

Answer (score 0):

If you only wish to fix Windows without reinstalling Ubuntu,
then do
[Startup Repair](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/performance/windows-boot-issues-troubleshooting) to fix the boot problem
for booting directly into Windows without passing through Grub.

But if you would rather fix Grub, use the
[Rescatux & Super Grub2 Disk](https://www.supergrubdisk.org/rescatux/).